Est-ce que « dérochage » s’emploie en informatique ?
Dans l’épisode du 6 Août 2024, intitulé « Comment écouter le passé ? » du podcast Autour de la question de RFI on discute la synthèse authentique des paysages sonores d’autrefois. En qualifiant l’effort exigé, l’invitée dit (ou semble dire) au repère de temps de 11:01,

Et c'est à peu près 390 heures ou un peu plus de travail entre le dérochage,  la création de l'histoire et la spatialisation.

J’ai l’impression que cette affaire de dérochage correspond à ce qu’on appelle en anglais « cleaning up data », mais je n’ai pas réussi à confirmer l’interprétation.  Selon TLF, en plus du sens littéral d’enlèvement des roches du fond d’une rivière, d’un chenal, etc., le mot s’emploie aussi pour signifier l’acte de nettoyer ou polir les surfaces métalliques. Mais si on cherche « clean up data » chez Linguee, on ne trouve qu’assainir, épurer, préparer, et (ce qui est le plus fréquent) nettoyer. Et si on cherche « dérochage de données » on ne reçoit rien de pertinent.
Est-ce que j’ai bien compris ce dérochage ? Une interprétation alternative qui m’est venue s’agit de minage, de prospection, d’extraction. Mais cela me semble moins probable.

En informatique, je ne crois pas.

En informatique on parlerait de mise en qualité des données.

Dérocher/dérochage ne s'emploie pas en informatique. Le mot est rare et correspond à ce que tu as trouvé dans le TLFi mais ce n'est pas ce que dit la personne interviewée dans le podcast. Elle parle de dérushage:
Wikipedia :

Dérushage
Première étape du montage d'un programme audiovisuel : il consiste à sélectionner les vidéos à utiliser lors du montage, appelés rushs, et à les transférer sur la plate-forme de montage.

Ce n'est donc pas non plus un terme d'informatique mais un terme employé dans le milieu du cinéma, du reportage, de la video, etc. dans le cadre de l'utilisation d'un logiciel de montage. On dérushait déjà du temps de la pellicule mais le verbe n'était probablement pas encore apparu (j'ai trouvé les premières occurrences dans un livre de 1988).

Ah ! Je connais bien le terme  anglais rushes. Mais je n’imaginais pas qu’il était emprunté en français, et encore moins transformé en… dirait-t-on privatif? Et j’étais fourvoyé par la traduction automatique d’Apple, qui m’a mis sur la piste de dérochage.

@PaulTanenbaum Oui, pas facile de les distinguer à l'oreille, les prononciations étant quasiment identiques et probablement même parfois indifférenciables. Que veux-tu dire par privatif ? Une appropriation complète ?

Où est passé l'informatique mentionnée dans la question?

@Frank - Voilà !

@jlliagre, dé- comme dépourvoir.  Et privatif dans le sens grammatical : marquant l’absence, la privation d’une chose.

@Frank, informatique dans le sens du traitement des données.

@PaulTanenbaum Ha, je comprends, oui. Le préfixe dé- signifie ici faire le "contraire" de ce qui a été fait précédemment, comme faire/défaire, (en)rouler/dérouler, sauf qu'en français, on n'a pas de verbe rusher. L'équivalent en anglais serait donc à l'image de do/undo, roll/unroll, un hypothétique "unrush" (qui n'existe pas).

J'entends bien "dérochage", mais  "dérushage" a  évidement plus de sens dans le contexte ("Malgré une bonne prise de son, il est souvent nécessaire de connaître quelques techniques de montage pour découper l’audio capté, normaliser son volume sonore et l’exporter dans un format compatible avec le support de diffusion". source CLEMI).

@Graffito Oui, les deux sont parfois indifférenciables à l'oreille mais le contexte les départage forcément.
